# Trying to upload large files>200 MB using Box V2 API gives exception

Tags: box-api

```
at com.box.boxjavalibv2.resourcemanagers.BoxResourceManager.tryCastObject(BoxResourceManager.java:205)
at com.box.boxjavalibv2.filetransfer.BoxFileUpload.execute(BoxFileUpload.java:58)
at com.box.boxjavalibv2.resourcemanagers.BoxFilesManager.uploadFile(BoxFilesManager.java:224)
```

I'm able to upload a file =100 MB
My user has available space >200 MB

Comment: Interesting. What is your question?

Comment: what's the exception (not just the trace you listed)?